# LWC - handler on public array property change

Tags: lightning-web-components, public-reactive-properties

I have a child lwc which receives an array as a public property (@api inputArray), does some work on it, and then returns another array via events to the parent.

When the input array is changed by the parent, I want the code to run and the event to be sent. Currently, I have a for:each within the lwc.html that runs through the array (but displays nothing), then when the inputArray is changed, the lwc is re-rendered and I can use the renderedCallback to send my event.

But it seems kind of awkward to have a for:each loop doing nothing in order to trigger the re-render and run this code.

What is the good and convenient way of recognising and handling change in a lwc public property? Or is what I'm doing already the best?

(For the sake of simplicity below, I've left out the code that is altering the array and just returning a string)

childLWC.js

```js
import { LightningElement, api } from 'lwc';

export default class FilterLWC extends LightningElement {
    
    @api inputArray;

    renderedCallback(){
        console.log('rendered');
        this.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('childEvent', {detail: {newList: "woooo" }}));
    }
}
```

childLWC.html

```
<template>
    <div>
        <template for:each={inputArray} for:item="arrayElement">
            <p key={arrayElement}>
            </p>
        </template>
    </div>
</template>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The appropriate way to deal with this is to make the API property a getter/setter pair...

```
@api get inputArray() {
    return this._inputArray;
}

set inputArray(value) {
    this._inputArray = value;

    this.reactToUpdate();
}
```